# How to inject a component instance in angular2

Tags: angular

Let's say I want to implement a lightbox component, which uses `<dialog>` to render its content. Something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'image-popup',
  template: `
  <dialog>
  ...
  </dialog>
`
})
export class ImagePopupComponent {
...
  show(): void {
    this.element.nativeElement.showModal();
  }
}
```

If I create an instance of this in the main app component, how can I enable its access from other components. For eg., in some descendant component, I have a button where I want the click to trigger show() on this dialog instance. In my use case, this component will have an imageUrl property, and the same component will be used multiple times to show different images.

Comment: Use a shared service. There are tons of similar questions with answers.

Comment: Martin's comment below looks correct. Please note that by default service injections are singletons. So you'll be receiving the same instance of 'MyModalService' in all your components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service for this.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyModalService {
    component: MyModal;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-modal',
})
export class MyModal {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef, modalService: MyModalService) {
        modalService.component = this;
    }

    show(): void {
        this.element.nativeElement.showModal();
    }
}
```

Then in some other component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'another',
})
export class AnotherComponent {
    constructor(private _modalService: MyModalService) {
    }

    buttonClicked() {
        this._modalService.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: With this method, will the MyModal template render automatically ? For exemple if MyModal use a bootstrap modal, and I use this.element.nativeElement.modal(), will the bootstrap modal appear automatically ?