# hidding button of another view angular2

Tags: angular

hello dears geek i have a problem with angular2:
I'm developing an application in angular2

```
(menuComponent, menuView.html)
(listProductComponent, listProductView.html)
(detailProductComponent, detailProductView.html)
```

i have a button in the menuView.html for add new Product like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a class="active" [routerLink]="['ListeProduct']">Product</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['ListeArticle']">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['ListeClients']">Clients</a></li>   
</ul>
<button  type="button" (click)="Add()" class="btn btn-primary    ajouter">Add</button>`
```

my `listProductView.html` is:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Code Product</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tr *ngFor="#product of products" >
        <td>{{product.code}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.cost}}</td>
    </tr>   
</table> `
```

what I need is when I click on one product of the `listProduct` to see the product detail in `detailProductView.html` is to hide the button Add from `menuView.html`.

Comment: This is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525472/how-to-inject-a-component-instance-in-angular2/35525956#35525956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could leverage a shared service with an `EventEmitter` property. One component will emit an event based on it and this other component will be notified by subscribing the `EventEmitter`. When the event is received, this component can set a property used to show / hide the button...

- Shared service

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class MenuService {
    addButtonEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }
  ```

  Don't forget to define the corresponding provider in the boostrap function to be able to share the same instance of the service for the whole application: `bootstrap(App, [ MenuService ]);
- `MenuComponent` component

  ```
  @Component({ ... })
  export class MenuComponent {
    showAdd: boolean = false;
    constructor(menuService: MenuService) {
      menuService.addButtonEvent.subscribe(
        (showAdd) => {
          this.showAdd = !this.showAdd;
        }
     );
   }
  ```

  }
- `ProductListComponent` component:

  ```
  export class ProductListComponent {
    constructor(private service: MenuService) {
    }

    toggleAddButton():void {
      this.addButton = this.addButton;
      this.service.addButtonEvent.emit(this.addButton);
    }
  }
  ```

See this question for more details of the implementation of this approach:

- [Toggle property in parent Component from Child Component in Angular2 (similar to $emit in AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719496/toggle-property-in-parent-component-from-child-component-in-angular2-similar-to/35719561#35719561)
- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)