# Angular 2 changing component variables on another component

Tags: angular

How can a component change a variable on another component. Example:

I have a component `app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <nav *ngIf="onMain == false">
       Hello
    </nav>
    `
})

export class AppComponent{
  onMain: Boolean;

  constructor(){
      this.onMain = false;
    }
}
```

I have another component which I want to change onMain in my app component `main.component.ts`

```
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: ``
})

export class MainComponent{

  constructor() {
      this.appComponent = AppComponent;
      this.appComponent.onMain = true;
    }
}
```

I would expect that Hello would disappear, but it doesn't. How can I have one component change the value on another component?

Comment: You can use `EventEmitter` in a **service**. Then let AppComponent subscribe it to get the event of the change.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, you have no connection between two components or maybe something is not correct in your code. If you have parent/child scenario you can use `@Input,@Output` of angular2. If you don't have parent/child scenario you can go with `EventEmitter,SharedService` of angular2. 
 
 ***[Working demo-EventEmitter way](http://plnkr.co/edit/VXAIZwQ2O2ZMHxHEzmvv?p=preview)***
 
I have considered `AppComponent` is a parentComponent and MainComponent as a child component. Using `SharedService & EventEmitter` concepts of `angular2`, I'm able to hide `AppComponent's` part of view by clicking a button which belongs to 'MainComponent's' view.

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import {Component,bind,CORE_DIRECTIVES,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {MainComponent} from 'src/MainComponent';
import {SharedService} from 'src/shared.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives:[MainComponent],
    template: `<h1>AppComponent {{onMain}}</h1>
    <div *ngIf="onMain == false">
       Hello
      <br> __________________________________<br>
    </div>

  <main-app></main-app>
    `
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  onMain: Boolean;

  constructor(ss: SharedService) {
      this.onMain = false;
      this.ss = ss;
    }



    ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.ss.getEmittedValue()
      .subscribe(item => this.onMain=item);
  }

}
```

**MainComponent.ts**

```
import {Component,bind,CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from 'src/shared.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',

    template: `<h1> MainComponent</h1>
    <button (click)="changeName()">Change Name</button>
    `
})

export class MainComponent {



    constructor(ss: SharedService) {
      this.ss = ss;
    }

    changeName() {
      this.ss.change();
    }
}
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
import {Component, Injectable,Input,Output,EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  @Output() fire: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   constructor() {
     console.log('shared service started');
   }

   change() {
    console.log('change started'); 
     this.fire.emit(true);
   }

   getEmittedValue() {
     return this.fire;
   }

}
```

Comment: Where does this.subscription come from on AppComponent? I'm getting an error that the property subscription does not exist on AppComponent

Comment: Have you added **`rx.js`** file? look at the **`index.html`** in my plunker demo. you will find necessary referencing of required files. And if answers suits your requirement you should accept it as an answer so other may refer to it as an answer.

Comment: @micronyks thanks. Can you also share the package.json? Because things are not working with latest platform and other packages please.

Comment: @RaviManiyar. please look here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html for latest `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks @micronyks! This was exactly what I needed!!

Comment: How do we fire this (fire) event in the desired component. Can you please explain this?

Answer (score 10):

If there is no relation between components (I mean parent / child), you need to use a shared service with an `EventEmitter` property. One component will emit an event based on it and this other component will be notified by subscribing the `EventEmitter`. When the event is received, this component can set a property used to show / hide the button...

- Shared service

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class SharedService {
    onMainEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }
  ```

  Don't forget to define the corresponding provider in the boostrap function to be able to share the same instance of the service for the whole application: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
- `AppComponent` component

  ```
  @Component({ ... })
  export class AppComponent {
    onMain: boolean = false;
    constructor(service: MenuService) {
      sharedService.onMainEvent.subscribe(
        (onMain) => {
          this.onMain = onMain;
        }
     );
   }
  ```

  }
- `MainComponent` component:

  ```
  export class MainComponent {
    constructor(private service: SharedService) {
    }

    updateOnMain(onMain):void {
      this.service.onMainEvent.emit(onMain);
    }
  }
  ```

These questions for more details:

- [Delegation: EventEmitter or Observable in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/34402436#34402436)
- [hidding button of another view angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724724/hidding-button-of-another-view-angular2/35724990#35724990)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can change the variable value from one component to another one for this you have to
`inject` the component exported class into the parent component by doing so 
you are able to reach each and every method and variable of injected class (component).

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: `myTemplate.html`,
    directive: [AppComponent2]
})

export class AppComponent {
  variable1: boolean = true;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app2',
    templateUrl: `temp2.html`,
    providers: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppComponent2 {
  constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent){ }
  Fun(){
    console.log('Function Called');
    this.appComponent.variable1 = false;
  }
}


<button (click)='Fun()'>Change Variable</button>

{{appComponent.variable1}}
```

- **Updated** as per ng6 -

  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

Working Example http://plnkr.co/edit/fpYFueOnkm5sa4JfG7uX?p=preview

Comment: It will work with Angular 6? Could you please update the code if possible? Because i have tried to include @Directive for Angular 6, but no luck.

Comment: Yeah this should work with angular 6 as well, I'll Update answer shortly

Answer (score 2):

If you have a parent/child relationship you can use an event emitter to flip the variable with just a couple lines of code. There is no need to write a whole shared service.

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <nav *ngIf="onMain == false" (observableEvent)="onMain == true">
       Hello
    </nav>
    `
})
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-app',
    template: ``
})

export class MainComponent{
    @Output() observableEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {
      this.appComponent = AppComponent;
      this.observableEvent.emit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed with your comment. No need to code a whole service on this case.