# Angular: Get value as Input from Component in router outlet

Tags: angular, input, routes, angular-routing

My header has two different modes: burger and return. It depends on the component in the router outlet, which mode should be used.

`app.component.ts`:

```
<header-bar [mode]="getMenuMode()"></header-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Right now the `header-bar` component has an `@Input()` called mode, which calls `getMenuMode()` on the component. Of course this doesn't work - I don't really have an idea though how to approach this.

Comment: You can't use inputs or outputs for binding with components added by the router. Use instead a shared service.

Comment: Just got it working based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35739228/5243272