# Reset specific input text value when method call

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular5

how to clear textbox value from another component.

app.component.html

```
 <input id="search"
         type="text"
         class="form-control"
         name="criteria"
         placeholder="Search000"
         [(ngModel)]="_criteria"
         (ngModelChange)="criteriaChange()"
          >
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, [Angular 2 changing component variables on another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738355/angular-2-changing-component-variables-on-another-component)

This all depends on the relationship of these components and if you can get a handle of this component directly. Ex. in the testing case, I can easily change the property of any component.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just utilize JQuery and on the angular click event, I would just clear out the value; but if you want to use angular.

One way of achieving this is by utilizing @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(NameOfComponent) nameOfComponent: NameOfComponent;

this.nameOfComponent.whatEverYouWantToAccess.
```