# How to overlap component?

Tags: css, angular

I have the following angular component lets call it *child-component*

```
<div>
       <a-component-tag></a-component-tag>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
</div>
```

which is itself being rendered into another router-outlet like this

```
<div>
<top-component></top-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>
```

I would like the component that is rendered in the first router-outlet above to either render below *a-component-tag* or cover *a-component-tag*, depending on the user clicking a maximize, minimize button. It shouldn't cover anything but *a-component-tag* (i.e. it should not cover *top-component*).

This component is defined by

```
<div id="thiscomp" [ngclass]="max?cover:minimize">...</div>
```

I tried to define these two classes as

```
.cover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index:100;
}

.minimize {
   margin-top:30px;
}
```

but the cover class is not working: Some of the subcomponents in the *thiscomp* div are rendered above some stay minimized.

Comment: Hi, I removed the [tag:javascript] tag because there isn't any in this question. More precisely (for future reference), it's not _critically relevant_ to the question. Also, Angular is written in TypeScript, anyway. Someone may still propose a JavaScript _answer_, of course.

Comment: Following the suggestion of @Daniel Beck below, if you want to hide the parent component and display the child component take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738355/angular-2-changing-component-variables-on-another-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to change the order in which two DOM elements appear -- there are better techniques than absolute positioning available for that.

The javascript in this example is just for demo; the work is being done in the CSS:

```js
document.getElementById("example").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle('flip');
}
```

```css
#container {display: flex; flex-direction:column}

#container.flip {flex-direction: column-reverse}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="componentA">Component A</div>
  <div class="componentB">Component B</div>
</div>

<button id="example">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: I want component B to cover component A not flip them. Or maybe I am misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood -- I took "below" as meaning "on the page" not "in stacking order".  I'm not quite following your description of what you do want -- if you're trying to hide one component behind another might it be better to just v-if the background one out of existence?

Comment: ...er, ng-if.  Forgot which framework we were talking about :)

Comment: I actually like this solution. I tried both this solution and the ngIf on the top component and for now prefer flipping them as described above.